# Showing an Exception upon Clicking on a Row

Tags: ios

This code showing exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SelectHospitalViewController
>   returncityname:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
.h file
-(void)returncityname:(NSString*)CityList;

//.m file  
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {



        cell.textLabel.text = [self.SearchCityResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.CityList[indexPath.row];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [_CityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
-(void)back
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)IndexPath
    {
    if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        [self.delegate returncityname:[self.SearchCityResult objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row]];

    }
    else
    {

        [self.delegate returncityname:[_CityList objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row]];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I cannot find out the problem in this code that causes the error.
Could anyone help me??

Comment: Pleas provide code for rowClick and returncityname method

Comment: put exception break point and let me know and also let me know self.SearchCityResult and _cityList are contain string only

Comment: else
    {

        [self.delegate returncityname:[_CityList objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row]];
    }
It showing exception in this point..

Comment: in the console window type po _CityList and execute
all are string objects or any non-string object present

Comment: i couldn't understood..could u please wxplain me??

Comment: in debug area where all your NSlog prints.add debug points in else and when it stops write that command in debug area where nslog prints

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SelectHospitalViewController returncityname:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78781ce0'

Comment: Hi you just put a break point in the tableViewDidSelect method and in debug console window type
 " po  _CityList " and press enter

Comment: By seeing the code I don't think you need to call `returncityname` with delegate. Seems like the  `returncityname`  is defined in the same class which holds the tableview delegates. Try `[self returncityname:[_CityList objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row]];`

Comment: po_CityList
error: 'po_CityList' is not a valid command.

Comment: When i debug this after breakpoint than in the CityList all objects are show

Comment: put space between them  po _CityList

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that self.delegate is your custom protocol. If the self.delegate do not implement "returncityname:". It will cause this exception if you call [self.delegate returncityname:xx].

If "returncityname:" is an optional protocol method, you must detect if it is implement before call. like:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(returncityname:)]) {
    xxx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your delegate as following:

```
@property (nonatomic) id<YourDelegateClass> delegate;
```

So, you will be able to call the proper methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a protocol/delegate like so:

```
@protocol SelectHospitalDelegate : NSObject
-(void)returncityname:(NSString*)CityList;
@end
```

And your view controller needs an instance variable of that delegate

```
@interface SelectHospitalViewController : UIViewController
@property(strong) SelectHospitalDelegate delegate;
@end
```